# producing variable colors with decimal numbers

Tags: gnuplot

I created a file which looks like where the first column is the color line in decimal and the second column is y-axis. The x-axis is the row number.

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
...
```

Then I run this command

```
plot "test.dat" u 0:2:1 pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb variable
```

As you can see in the picture, the output contains a range of black to blue colors only.

[image]

Why?

How can I produce other colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have the choice between three options, `linecolor rgb variable`, `linecolor variable` and `linecolor palette`. Which one you use and how depends on your actual requirements.

1. When you use `linecolor rgb variable`, the value given in the last column is used as integer representation of an rgb-tuple, i.e. the lowest byte is the blue part, the second lowest the green part and the third byte is the red component. This is what you have.

   For using this option you must either have the full rgb-integer values in your data file, like

   ```
   0 13.5 # black 
   0 17 
   65280 12 # green (255 * 2**8)
   0 19.3 
   16711680 14.7 # red (255 * 2**16)
   65280 10 
   16711680 22
   ```

   and then use

   ```
   plot 'test.txt' using 0:2:1 linecolor rgb variable pt 7
   ```

   Alternatively you save the red, green and blue components in one column each and use a gnuplot function to calculate the rgb-integer:

   ```
   0   0   0 13.5 # black 
   0   0   0 17 
   0   255 0 12 # green
   0   0   0 19.3 
   255 0   0 14.7 # red (255 * 2**16)
   0   255 0 10 
   255 0   0 22
   ```

   and then use

   ```
   rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
   plot 'test.txt' using 0:4:(rgb($1,$2,$3)) linecolor rgb variable pt 7
   ```
2. Using `linecolor variable` would use the last column as `linetype` index. Large indices are wrapped to the set of defined linetype:

   ```
   set xrange [0:1000]
   plot '+' using 1:1:0 linecolor variable pt 7
   ```

   [image]
3. Using `linecolor palette` uses the last column as index for the color palette:

   ```
   set xrange [0:1000]
   plot '+' using 1:1:0 linecolor palette pt 7
   ```

   [image]

Which variant you use may depend both on the number of different colors and the distribution of the colors.

Comment: Yes, if you have a fixed palette, the colors are selected from this. If you want different colors you must either change your palette or define appropriate linetypes, see my edited answer.

Comment: Excuse me... I understand what you are saying. However that doesn't fit my need. defining a palette will create a range of colors. So the first point is black and the last point is red. If you apply the methods on my example (example in my updated post), you will see the incorrect behavior. I need to define a column for the colors in my input file in order to correctly group/cluster them.

Comment: Well, it is quite hard to see what fits your needs if you give information piecewise. The three variants I mentioned are basically what you can do. If you cannot define an appropriate palette, you should use `linecolor rgb variable` like you already do, but you must have the correct integer value in the first column, i.e. `16711680` for red (` = 255 * 2**16`), `65280` for green (`= 255 * 2**8`) and `255` for blue. Of course also any value in between. Or you can save the r,g and b values in the first three data file columns and use `rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)`...

Comment: ... for the conversion with `plot 'test.txt' using 0:4:(rgb($1,$2,$3)) linecolor rgb variable pt 7`.

Comment: I think I got what you said. Your current answer is correct for the first problem (first figure). So I will remove the second part and will create a new post if necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: I expanded my comment regarding the first option into the answer.