# How to add colors to every point in gnuplot from inside the point file

Tags: gnuplot, rgb, gnu

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427704/vary-point-color-based-on-column-value-for-multiple-data-blocks-gnuplot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717805/vary-point-color-in-gnuplot-based-on-value-of-one-column) answer I understood that changing the colours of every point is possible, but:

- it has to be defined using `set palette model RGB defined ()`, hence
  if I want 100 different colours I will have to define all of them
- the colour of the point is specified just before it is drawn.

My question is, is there a way to avoid all of the above, for example modify my data file as follows:

```
x y z R   G   B
1 2 3 0   255 255 
5 6 2 255 0   0
```

And have the according point drawn with the specified colour?

Comment: See also my answer to [producing variable colors with decimal numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25865368/2604213).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following on gnuplot 4.6+:

```
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
plot "data.dat" using 1:2:(rgb($3,$4,$5)) with points lc rgb variable
```

From the manual:

> **1.17.1.3 rgbcolor variable**
>
> *variable* tells the program to read  RGB color information for each
>   line in the data file.  This requires a  corresponding additional
>   column in the  using specifier.  The  extra column is interpreted as a
>   24-bit packed RGB triple.  If the value  is provided directly in the
>   data file it is easiest to give it as a  hexidecimal value (see
>   'rgbcolor').  Alternatively, the  using  specifier can contain an
>   expression that evaluates to a 24-bit RGB color  as in the example
>   below.  Text colors are similarly set using *tc  rgbcolor variable*.

Comment: If you could be so kind, and extend your answer to one more thing, I am plotting not points but rather lines, what happens if I change `points` to `lp` is that the line has the colour of the point I start with, is there a way I could make the colour of the line different/a colour that will translate from begin->end. 
A source where I could read on this would be good as well.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct solution for this one; each line segment will be drawn with a color; gradients need an indirect, complex approach. See [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/using-a-palette-as-line-color/) and [here](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/gradient-colored-curve-in-gnuplot0.html).